# Unrecognized configuration section system.applicationHost

Tags: iis, web-config, denial-of-service

I was planning to add `MinFileBytesPerSec` attribute with in `system.applicationHost` configuration to overcome DOS vulnerability. However as soon as I add `system.applicationHost` within Configuration section of `web.config`, and run the application, it throws me an error stating:

> Unrecognized configuration section system.applicationHost

I verified and I could find `system.applicationHost` defined in `ApplicationHost.config` file, and since I am using IIS 7.5, `system.applicationHost` should be available with default installation.

I am stuck with this issue of why `system.applicationHost` is not being recognized, any suggestion will be very helpful.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It is not allowed for a web.config file to define anything about `<system.applicationHost>`. Such changes must go to applicationHost.config.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. I just overlooked a basic thing. Sorry on my part for it. Thanks a lot for you help again. :)